# Exclude a Specific Class when importing Package in Maven

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I am importing entities as shown below in MAVEN.

```
   <Import-Package>
            *,
            org.apache.camel.osgi,
            com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.*,
            org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*                
  </Import-Package>
```

How is it possible to exclude a specific class from being imported.
Forexample, I want all classes from org.apache.camel.osgi except for one.
How can I exclude that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't as you only import Packages.
As the directive you use is **Import-Package**. 
You should make yourself comfortable with OSGi Classloading and visibility of external dependencies.

With an Import-Package you declare your bundle will only work if that dedicated package is available. If that is not the case your bundle won't be resolved and your application logic won't be started.

With an Export-Package you declare which packages can be used by others.